# UITapGestureRecognizer does not work in specific iPhone devices

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a UITapGesture to some views. It is working fine only in iPhone 7 plus. The gesture method does not get called for other devices(iPhone 8, 6, 5s). Has anyone faced this kind of issue? I am just curious why is this happening? Has this something to do with Autolayout?

```
    let tabGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePassTap(_:)))

        tabGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
                self.passTabContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tabGesture)



    let textGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePassTap(_:)))
            textGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            self.passTextContainer.addGestureRecognizer(textGesture)

    @objc func handlePassTap(_ gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "passSegue", sender: currentPass)
    }
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible project?

Comment: Did you check `passTabContainer` and `passTextContainer` is properly tappable in other that device and also in front of screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There was a view on top of those gesture views that was blocking the tap. Resolved it now.